# Magento 2: Redirect to specific page on customer registration fail

Tags: magento2, customer, controllers, customer-account, customer-registration

I have made custom registration form which uses Magento's `createPost` for creating a new customer. On registration fail it is redirecting to `customer/account/create`

I would like it to redirect it to the custom form page again. How to achieve this?

There is no event in Magento for customer registration fail. Also if I want to create a preference of `CreatePost` controller I don't know how to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass some additional parameter with registration form post parameter to `CreatePost` controller, which identifies that the request is made from custom registration form.

And then you can check whether your custom parameter is available in post data, depending on it you can redirect the request to the custom registration page post registration failure.

Comment: @SuiyanKhot Is it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to replace redirect URL from  `customer/account/create/` to own in case of this query from your own page form.

Try to add the "[before](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#before-methods)" plugin for this method:

\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response::setRedirect

with something like this (it's a raw code - probably you need to avoid directly using the $_SERVER variable in magento, etc.):

```
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'you_custom_form_page_url_request') !== false
            && strpos($url, 'customer/account/create/') !== false
            && $code === 302
        ) {
            $url = 'you_custom_form_page_full_url';
        }
```